# strange behaviour on php

Tags: php, string, oop, octal

Can some one please tell me why I get odd results rurning the following code?

```
<?php
class Bank
{
    var $ID;
    var $balance;
    var $name;
    function bank($name,$id,$balance=0)
    {
        $this->ID=$id;
        $this->balance=$balance;
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    function getBalance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }
    function setBalance($bal)
    {
        $this->balance=$bal;
    }
    function getId()
    {
        return $this->ID;
    }
    function setId($i)
    {
        $this->ID=$i;
    }
)
$b= new bank(yaniv,027447002, 15000);
```

Now when I try to echo:

```
$b->ID
```

Instead of the expected 027447002 I get an odd 6180354,
but if I initiate the object like this :

```
$b=new bank(yaniv,'027447002',15000);
```

(notice I quoted the id property) it works OK.
Any suggestion why is this happening and what is the right way to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

027447002 is in [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), as it prefixed with a zero. Convert that to decimal and you get 6180354!

See the [manual page on integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) for details.

Comment: amazing...+1 to my knowledge =)

Answer (score 3):

Because of the initial zero, it is interpreted as an octal number.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

If the number should be left padded with zeros when printed (they are always a specific length) then you can use [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) to convert the stored integer to a zero padded string.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the leading zero, because it makes PHP treat the number as an octal number.

Answer (score 2):

Numeric literals with leading zeroes are how you specify something in octal (base 8).  If you write `27447002` instead of `027447002` you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic base conversion.  You don't even need all that class code to see this in action

```
echo 027447002;
```

The thing is that 027447002, in terms of numbers, is octal (base-8) - *not* a zero-filled decimal (base-10) integer.

Answer (score 1):

I have one comment besides what everyone else is saying.

It appears you want a 0 padded number, right? A nine digit number that's padded with zeros on the left?

Think about using str_pad function. Like so:

```
...
function bank($name, $id, $bal=0)
{
 ...
 $this->id = str_pad($id, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
 ...
}
...
```

Then in your function you can call:

```
$b = new bank('John Doe', 12345678, 1.25);
```

If you output id, it would be padded

012345678

Comment: thanks so much for that
actually i will be getting this number as an input from the user and he'll probably enter the zero so i need to find a way to get that number as a string or something like that... :)

Comment: Just to tell you, php makes no distinction on strings. Everything is a string, and everything is a number. So if a user enters a "number" on a form, it'll be treated as both a number and string, there will be no need to "convert" other than to ensure that it's a valid input.

Comment: Also, look up the is_ checks. To check for numeric input, try is_numeric. It will tell you if an input is numeric.

Comment: Finally, your sample code explicitly told php to use octal values (which wasn't your intention). In the original code, if a user enters 012345678 from the _POST/_GET variable on a webpage, it would work AS EXPECTED

Comment: Thanks Daniel :) your help is highly appreciated!
 Thanks so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

As everyone rightly said - this is considered an octal value by default. I think the class constructor should be testing that it is a valid integer, and initiating the class should [typecast](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the value...

```
function bank($name, $id, $balance=0)
{
    if (is_int($id))
      $this->ID=$id;
    else
      throw new Exception('ID is not integer');

    // and validate these too!
    $this->balance=$balance;
    $this->name=$name;
}

$b= new bank('yaniv', (int)027447002, 15000);
```

Hope that helps!